# How to Delete Data from Two tables in single query

Tags: c#, sql, query-optimization

I have two tables: `Accounts`, which contains the information of accounts that a user has, and `AccountUsers`, which contains the list of users that have accounts in aforementioned `Accounts` table.

If I have to delete a user then I would have to delete them from both tables where as `AccountUsers` will have one row of that user where as other may have many because a single user can have many accounts.

I wrote the following code that works well and deletes the row from both tables, but whenever there are multiple rows in the second table it fails to delete them and `ExecuteNonQuery()` returns 0, which means 0 rows are affected.

I would like to know if it can be done in a single line. Also, how can it be done for multiple rows in the second table, as my existing code only works if there is single row.

Code:

```
public static bool DeleteUser(int UserId)
        {
            if (ConnectDatabase())
            {
                sql_cmd = new SqlCommand();
                sql_cmd.Connection = sql_con;
                sql_cmd.Parameters.Add("@userId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = UserId;
                sql_cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM AccountsUsers WHERE Id = @userId";

                if (sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    sql_cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    sql_cmd.Connection = sql_con;
                    sql_cmd.Parameters.Add("@userId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = UserId;
                    sql_cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Accounts WHERE userId = @userId";
                    if (sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                        return false;

                }
                else
                    return false;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is bit of a logic flaw in you code. It there is one record in the second table, ExecuteNonQuery will return 1, but it there are more, it will **not** return one, but some other number. I would change the conditional after the second delete to:

```
if (sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 1)
```

Which raises the question - if there are no records in the second table, do you want your function to return false?

Comment: This was the fault what you told .actually it returned 2 when it deleted two rows and so on.i never thought of it, i thought there are only 2 values.0,1

Answer (score 2):

I may be being too simplistic but you can probably just do the following - There is nothing wrong with including multiple sql statements in a single command separated by a semicolon:

```
    static bool DeleteUser(int UserId)
    {
        if (ConnectDatabase())
        {
            sql_cmd = new SqlCommand();
            sql_cmd.Connection = sql_con;
            sql_cmd.Parameters.Add("@userId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = UserId;
            sql_cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Accounts WHERE userId = @userId;DELETE FROM AccountsUsers WHERE Id = @userId;";

            if (sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;               
    }
```

It is definitely best practice to delete from the Accounts table first before the AccountsUsers because usually the Accounts table would have a foreign constraint on AccountsUsers table. This means no rows could be deleted in AccountsUsers before corresponding row in Accounts deleted first.

Comment: Yeh works but i was not getting it the problem was what `Steve Mallory` Told be

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to delete the Accounts first, but it's not clear exactly which direction your foreign key is going in.

You cannot delete from two tables in a single query generally, but you can make a transaction and have two DELETE statements within the transaction.

You can also use a cascading delete constraint so that you only delete from the parent table (but I rarely recommend that).

Comment: In MySQL, you can.
`DELETE FROM AccountsUsers, Accounts
USING AccountsUsers INNER JOIN Accounts
WHERE AccountsUsers.Id = Accounts.userId
AND AccountsUsers.Id = @userId`

Comment: in `Accounts`table there is primary key named Id but what i am using is the userId column that is the column that i populate while i insert the value in the database table.